# Как правильно использовать цикл (in range) или (of range)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pagination

Нашел в интернет функцию реализующий pagination:

```
    var calculatePages = function(num, last){
    var current = num,
        last = last,
        delta = 2,
        left = current - delta,
        right = current + delta + 1,
        range = [],
        rangeWithDots = [],
        l;

    for (var i = 1; i <= last; i++) {
        if (i == 1 || i == last || i >= left && i < right) {
            range.push(i);
        }
    }

    for (var i of range) {
        if (l) {
            if (i - l === 2) {
                rangeWithDots.push(l + 1);
            } else if (i - l !== 1) {
                rangeWithDots.push('...');
            }
        }
        rangeWithDots.push(i);
        l = i;
    }

    return rangeWithDots;
},
```

Работает отлично на всех браузерах кроме Internet Explorer 11..
Ругается на использование `of` in `if (var i of range)`

Заменил на `in` скрипт сыпится и работает некорректно..

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: `for...of` возвращает в `i` значение, тогда как `for...in` - ключ. Нужно ещё `i = range[i]` добавить.

Comment: обычно делается так: ставится babel, пишется в ES6, ставится gulp с нужным модулем, который  при сборке смотрит указанные браузеры и компилит соответствующе (то есть если хоть один указан, который еще не поддерживает ES6 - то компилит в ES5)...... в целом надо определиться вам на какие браузеры у вас расчет

Comment: range.forEach(function(i) {
});

Comment: Спасибо коллеги, помогло с i = range[i]